# How can I make certain text always appear bold?

Tags: css, text

I'm using tumblr CSS and I want certain symbols, like `/` (slash) to always appear in **bold** even when the main text is not. I know I can use `<b>/</b>`, but I was wondering if there is another way.

For example, I know how to format all `<small>` text to appear in bold:

```
small { 
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I would like to use the same method to automatically transform `/` to **bold**.

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot detect content, it can only style elements.

you can use JS to detect words or characters and put them inside elements and bold them.

Comment: Hi. Could you explain what you mean exactly?

Comment: hi.refer to Bhuwan's answer below. an example in action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` jQuery.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var str = $("div").html().replace(/\//g, "<b>/</b>");
//console.log(str)
$("div").html(str).wrapInner("<pre></pre>");
```

```css
b {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales nisl nec sapien aliquet, a commodo justo tincidunt.
    b {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
      background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but it just rendered the page into code :/ This seemed like the most promising fix but sadly, nope. :(

Comment: @mtndwells what do you mean by ***just rendered the page into code***

Comment: I added the bits of code to the various locations in my tumblr code but it just rendered the page into numbers and whatnot. See here for a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/nPg9FXG.png Then I moved the code and the page seemed to appear fine - but the code did not actually work.

Comment: [explanation] I placed the **first** and **last** segments of your code between </style> and </head> and it didn't change anything. So then I tried placing them between </body> and </script> and it "_rendered the full page of code_". (sorry for my lack of technical terms, you might be able to tell I'm just a hobbyist, trying to bend her tumblr to her will ^n^).

Comment: thanks for editing the code :) however, I've realised (though it may be fiddly to do it each time) simply adjusting each bit of code with <b> is far less hassel.